# How to automatically check the previously checked items?

Tags: android

I have list of items with check boxes using this code:

```
            ProcessList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
            ProcessList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,nameList ));
            ProcessList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            ProcessList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

I am getting items checked list from:

```
ProcessList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
    selectApp = (String) ProcessList.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

I am storing all checked list in array and now I want that the previously 'checked' items automatically 'checks' on restart of my app. Is there any way to do it ? (by extending my above code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an automatic way.

Overload the ArrayAdapter class and override the function

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

in a way which returns checked or not based on you previous array.